# Convert specific values in column in data frame

Tags: r

I'm have a data frame consisting of 1 column named 'x' with 35 rows of the letters A,B,C,D,E. I want to create another column in where all rows of x that are of value 'B' to change to 'Q', of value 'C' to change to 'Z' and all other values to remain the same. Alternatively,these changes could occur within the original column x itself. I could write a function, loop, or apply function but I'm thinking R has something simpler to do this. Here is the data:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-sample(LETTERS[1:5],35,replace=TRUE)
z<-data.frame(x)
z
```

Thanks guys....Can't seem to figure out what to google!

Comment: Awesome guys...Appreciate the base solution as well as the package solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `recode` from `library(car)`

```
z$x
#[1] B B C E B E E D D A B A D B D C D E B D E B D A B B A B E B C C C A E
#Levels: A B C D E

library(car)
z$new <- recode(z$x, "'B'='Q';'C'='Z'")
z$new
#[1] Q Q Z E Q E E D D A Q A D Q D Z D E Q D E Q D A Q Q A Q E Q Z Z Z A E
#Levels: A D E Q Z
```

If we need a `character` output, it can be specified

```
recode(z$x, "'B'='Q';'C'='Z'", as.factor.result=FALSE)
```

Also, there is a `levels` argument if we don't need to sort the order

```
recode(z$x, "'B'='Q';'C'='Z'", levels=c('A', 'Q', 'Z', 'D', 'E'))
```

Comment: Both work but I like this solution because the code is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's really very simple with the `chartr` (character translation) function:

```
z$new <- chartr("BC", "QZ", z$x)
```

You might notice that the original was a "factor" variable and the new column became character".

```
> str(z)
'data.frame':   35 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x  : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 2 2 3 5 2 5 5 4 4 1 ...
 $ new: chr  "Q" "Q" "Z" "E" ...
```